# C program doesn't print text when trying to access string data using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I'm going through "C Programming: A Modern Approach" by K.N. King right now. This program is taken from "Section 12 - Pointers and Arrays", Project 1b. Roughly, the goal is: Write a program that reads a message, then prints the reverse of the message. Store the message in an array, and keep track of the current position in the array using a pointer.

Currently, I'm just trying to get the message to print normally before I try and make it print backwards. I'm frustrated because my printMessage() function is 1:1 with the print_message() function from [here](https://github.com/fordea/c-programming-a-modern-approach/blob/master/ch12/Projects/01.c), however when the program is run and some text is entered, it just prints out a blank line. This happens if the line within the for-loop of printMessage() is changed to 'printf("%c", *p);' as well.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH 100

int readMessage(char msg[]);
void printMessage(char msg[], int len);

/* finish later
 void printMessageReversed(char msg[], int len); */

int main(void){
    int msg_length;
    char c[MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];

    printf("Enter a message: ");
    msg_length = readMessage(c);

    printf("Length: %d", msg_length);

    printf("\nMessage: ");
    printMessage(c, msg_length);

    return 0;
}

int readMessage(char msg[]){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; (*msg = getchar()) != '\n'; i++);
    return i;
}

void printMessage(char msg[], int len){
    char *p;

    for(p = msg; p < msg + len; p++){
        putchar(*p);
    }
}
```

Wondering if anyone can help identify my problem? I'm sure it's something painfully obvious or naive that I'm just missing. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use pass by reference instead of pass by value to `readMessage()` function.

Comment: @Shravan40: No, that's not it. The `msg` parameter is a pointer.

Comment: @KeithThompson : Yes, you are right. I realized it as soon as i saw your answer.

Comment: @Shravan40: C does not support pass by reference! It is strictly pass by value.

Comment: @Olaf: Of course -- but passing a pointer (by value) can give you the equivalent functionality of pass-by-reference.

Comment: Apart from the lack of increment others have commented, you have not written a `nul` terminator at the end of the input to make the array a "string", in `readMessage`

Comment: @Olaf : In C, Pass-by-reference is simulated by passing the address of a variable (a pointer) and dereferencing that address within the function to read or write the actual variable. This will be referred to as "C style pass-by-reference."

Comment: I know this is just a beginner project, but try to include correct error handling into your projects as soon as possible. Read up on en.cppreference.com about the functions you use.

Comment: first thing - use a debugger to see whats happening

Comment: @Shravan40: A pointer is an object of its own. A reference is not. For instance try getting the address of a reference and a pointer. In C you pass a pointer to an object **by value**. And no, it is not "reffered to C-style pass-by-reference". It is simply called pass by address/pointer! But feel free to provide a reference to the standard which states me wrong.

Comment: @KeithThompson: A reference has no value of its own. A pointer is an object of its own. Let's not increase confusion by bringing in references into C.

Comment: @Olaf: I wasn't referring to C++-style references. "Pass-by-reference" has a more general meaning. But yes, using the word "reference" could cause some confusion to someone who's been exposed to both C and C++ but might not be entirely clear on how they differ. To summarize my point: Passing a pointer value (a.k.a. an address) is a way to simulate the "pass-by-reference" feature that exists in some other languages.

Comment: @Olaf: See also the standard's definition of a *pointer type* ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.2.5p20: "A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference
to an entity of the referenced type." Again, this is unrelated to C++ "reference" types.\

Comment: @KeithThompson: I very well know that. I wanted to point out that a pointer is an object of its own as the paragraph you cited states clear. I don't see much problem just saying "pass a pointer to ..." instead of "pass a reference to". And yes, that might be nit-picky, but you much better than I know about false assumptions of beginners here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int readMessage(char msg[]){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; (*msg = getchar()) != '\n'; i++);
    return i;
}
```

Each character is assigned to `*msg` (equivalently to `msg[0]`). The `msg` pointer is never updated and never indexed by `i`, so you never assign values to the remaining characters in the array whose initial element is pointed to by `msg`.

Replacing `*msg` by `msg[i]` is one partial solution. Note that this still doesn't write a null `'\0'` terminator into `msg`, so the `msg` array does not contain a string. But since your `printMessage` function doesn't require a string (it takes a `len` argument), that's not strictly necessary. Still, if you're going to operator on the array in other ways, it's probably a good idea to null-terminate it.

Also, as chux points out in a comment, you have an infinite loop if `getchar()` returns `EOF` before returning `'\n'` (on Unix that can happen if you type Ctrl-D twice in the middle of a line, or if you're reading from a file), and it has no protection against a buffer overrun.

Comment: so you need `msg[i] = getchar()`

Comment: Thank you! Altered the for-loop to read `for(c = msg; (*msg = getchar()) != '\n'; msg++, i++);` and it works perfectly now.

Comment: @pm100 and yes that would also work just as well, thanks :)

Comment: Also realise the example I just gave is probably overcomplicated so I'll try and cut it down a bit.

Comment: Side issues: `for(i = 0; (*msg = getchar()) != '\n'; i++);` is potential infinite loop upon reading `EOF` and it has no buffer over-run protection.

Comment: @chux ended up going with Jamal's suggestion below. Seems to be the neatest while still being legible.

Comment: @Sato  "legible" vs. "code correctness" --> your call.  Might want to avoid life critical apps for a while.

Comment: @chux what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

Use it like that :

```
int readMessage(char msg[]){
    int i;
        for (i = 0; (*(msg + i) = getchar()) != '\n'; i++);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: This is far more concise than everything I was trying. Thanks!

Comment: @WeatherVane agreed, but for the purposes of this chapter of the book I'm going to try and stick entirely to pointers, just so I can get used to them.

Comment: @Sato yeah, but the argument was an array (although that decays to a pointer). Another point: please be aware that if the argument was `int msg[]` instead of `char msg[]` there is no size adjustment required when using `*(msg + i) = getchar()` - just as with array indexing, the pointer arithmetic takes care of the size for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Write a program that reads a message, then prints the reverse of the message

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH 100
int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    char c[MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
    printf("Enter a message: ");
    fgets(c, sizeof c, stdin);
    printf("Reverse Order\n");
    i = 0;
    while (c[i] != '\0') {
        if (c[i] == ' ' || c[i] == '\n') {
            for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && c[j] != ' '; j--)
                printf("%c", c[j]);
            printf(" ");
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
Enter a message: Stackoverflow

Reverse Order
wolfrevokcatS
```

Try it with [ideone](http://ideone.com/zVQbqt).